# How to fill a Django custom multiplechoicefield with choices

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form with a search box that uses jQuery to fill a multipleChoiceField. I need to use a custom multipleChoiceField so I can control the validation and only check if the choice exists, not if it was one of the original choices as a modelMultipleChoiceField with a queryset would. However, the custom multipleChoiceField renders on the page as empty until you enter something in the search box to fill it with choices via jQuery. I would like it to render with a few choices to begin with instead.

```
class ArticleMultipleChoiceField(forms.MultipleChoiceField):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(ArticleMultipleChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      include_articles = [article.id for article in Article.objects.order_by('-sub_date')[:5]]
      self.choices = Article.objects.filter(id__in=include_articles).order_by('-sub_date')
```

In this form, I get the error "Article object is not iterable". I have also tried changing that self.choices to self.data, self.queryset, and self.initial, and in all those 3 cases, I keep getting an empty multiple choice field instead.

How can I use a queryset to provide the initial set of choices here?

Here is the form it is used in:

```
class StorylineAddArticleForm(forms.Form):
  articleSearchBox = forms.CharField(label="Search to narrow list below:")
  include_articles = [article.id for article in Article.objects.order_by('-sub_date')[:5]]
  articles = ArticleMultipleChoiceField()
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StorylineAddArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['articleSearchBox'].required = False
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Field('articleSearchBox'),
        Field('articles'),
        ButtonHolder(
            Submit('submit', 'Add', css_class='button white')
        )
        )
```

Also, this is being rendered by Crispy Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choices` doesn't accept a QuerySet as an argument, it needs a list or tuple of two-tuples with acceptable values. See the documentation on `choices` here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#field-choices .

In this case you need to turn your `Article` queryset into a list or tuple of the above format.